# How to set a group with "due in 3 days" with org-super-agenda?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

`:deadline future` shows todo items with deadlines. I want to make a group with todo items due in 3 days, i.e. somewhat like:

```
:deadline before (today+3d)
```

I checked user manual and found it suggests using some string that can be processed by "org-time-string-to-absolute". I am novice to elisp and got stuck there.

Comment: `:deadline before` requires a specific date string like `"2021-05-28 13:37:43"`. What you require is something that can be evaluated daily. Look at `:pred` option. It will probably help but will require knowledge of lisp code.

Comment: Thanks. Would it better if I could modifiy the example (tried but failed) in:
https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda/blob/master/examples.org#concrete-dates

(-let* (((sec minute hour day month year dow dst utcoff) (decode-time))
        (last-day-of-month (calendar-last-day-of-month month year))
        (target-date
         ;; A hack that seems to work fine.  Yay, Postel!
         (format "%d-%02d-%02d" year month (1+ last-day-of-month)))
        (org-super-agenda-groups
         `((:deadline (before ,target-date))
           (:discard (:anything t)))))
  (org-todo-list))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit hacky too but check if it works

```
(-let* (((sec minute hour day month year dow dst utcoff)
     (decode-time (+ (* 3 86400) (float-time)))) ;; 3 days
        (target-date
         (format "%d-%02d-%02d" year month day))
        (org-super-agenda-groups
         `((:deadline (before ,target-date))
           (:discard (:anything t)))))
  (org-todo-list))
```

Comment: Thanks! It work as I expected. But I still need to figure out how to combine the code with my config.el that contains other groups such as: